# Is it possible to add class active without using a href?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a 1 pager website but I am using a js to avoid seeing the hash in the url.
HTML:

```
<ul class="click crsl">
    <li><a class="page1 dot active"></a></li>
    <li><a class="page2 dot"></a></li>
    <li><a class="page3 dot"></a></li>
    <li><a class="page4 dot"></a></li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".page1").click(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#pageOne").offset().top
        }, 1000);
    });
    <-- up to page4 and #pageFour -->
</script>
```

All tutorials are showing me how to add/remove the class active to `li a` tags but they all use `a href="#idOfDiv".
It'll cause my first script useless because the url will be

> http://mywebpage.com/#pageOne

Comment: Just use `addClass()`. The `href` and classes have nothing to do with each other

Comment: Just check my solution it will work on every situation

Comment: @NikhilGhuse yes your answer is correct. Can't accept answers in 6mins

Comment: anyway can you check the changes on my question? sorry about that

Comment: Why not....? yes you can

Comment: I can't there is a restriction

Comment: Let me check your updated Question

Comment: But you wont mention id over there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156671/discussion-between-john-doe-and-nikhil-ghuse).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
   <ul class="click crsl">
     <li><a class="page1 dot active"></a></li>
     <li><a class="page2 dot"></a></li>
     <li><a class="page3 dot"></a></li>
     <li><a class="page4 dot"></a></li>
  </ul>
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("li a").click(function() {
     $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#pageOne").offset().top
     }, 1000);
      $('.active').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
});

<-- up to page4 and #pageFour -->
 </script>
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers

Answer (score 3):

You can just add the class within your `click` handler:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".dot").click(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#pageOne").offset().top
        }, 1000);
        $('.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: @NikhilGhuse This answer was submitted about 30 seconds earlier.

Comment: No worries guys, we got him the right answer and that's what matters.

Comment: yes it was.. because he added the same line that I have other than his answer thats why...